# Sending cookie in GET request in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm having some issues with an APP I'm developing. I'm making a GET request to a URL in order to get a XML file. Since it's a large file, it will be cached for, at least, 1 month as it doesn't change that much.

I've simulated the request with Python easily because the only mandatory thing is to have a cookie which the page assigns to you once you enter the page.

Here is the code, in Python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests

cookies = requests.get("http://www.someweb.com:9005/someDIR/index.jspx").cookies
data = requests.get("http://www.someweb.com:9005/someDIR/Results?op=lp&ls=All&t=0.41461605788208544", cookies=cookies).content
print data
```

I've tried to receive and send the cookie with cURL in PHP but I'm unable to do that. Any hints?

Comment: Removed PHP tag and added Python

Comment: Hmmm editing back since I'm trying to do this in PHP as I already achieved with Python

Comment: Please, read the question. I'm saying I'm able to do this with Python but *unable* to do with PHP and request for help since I don't know how I can retrieve the cookie from a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php

$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

$ch = curl_init ("http://www.someweb.com:9005/someDIR/index.jspx");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

$ch = curl_init ("http://www.someweb.com:9005/someDIR/Results?op=lp&ls=All&t=0.41461605788208544");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

echo $output;

?>
```